# Restrict a regex to only search between two points

Tags: python, regex

How do I restrict which parts of the text are searched using regular expressions? Given the example below, say I wanted to get the details of customer02. If I use

Name:\s*(.+)

then obviously I will get 3 results. So I want to restrict it to only search under the details for customer02 and stop when it gets to customer03. I could of course use an index of the results (ie results = ['Mr Smith','Mr Jones','Mr Brown'], therefore results[1]) but that seems clumsy.

> [Customer01]
>
> Name: Mr Smith
>
> Address: Somewhere
>
> Telephone: 01234567489
>
> [Customer02]
>
> Name: Mr Jones
>
> Address: Laandon
>
> Telephone:
>
> [Customer03]
>
> Name: Mr Brown
>
> Address: Bibble
>
> Telephone: 077764312

Comment: You might be able to do something messy like Customer01.*?Name:\s*(.+) which would ensure that it finds the first name after Customer01.

Comment: I would use `xx\]\sName:\s*(.+)$` where xx is the number but otherwise this is exactly the way to go.

Comment: Hi, this is the kind of thing I was looking for. Usually I would break the data down in python to slice up the data better, but I was really looking for a pure regex solution.

Comment: ... although I need to work out how to get it to work on the other parts like "address" 
:-)

Comment: For Address and anything else later on, ".*?" is your friend. You can just do xx].*?Address:\s*(.*?)\n That would look for the first instance of "Address," or whatever, after whatever customer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is what I came up with (sorry if it's a bit messy)
re.compile("\[Customer03\](?:.|\s)*?Address:\s*(.+)\n")
which works apart from when the the value is empty, such as Customer02 Telephone ... then it captures the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specific boundaries to search between and you're looking to get a capture group, why not just do:


`import re

text = "[Customer01]\nName: Mr Smith\nAddress: Somewhere\nTelephone: 01234567489\n[Customer02]\nName: Mr Jones\nAddress: Laandon\nTelephone:\n[Customer03]\nName: Mr Brown\nAddress: Bibble\nTelephone: 077764312"

blah = re.search("[Customer02]\nName:\s*(.*?)\n", text)

print blah.group(1)`

This returns "Mr Jones". I think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is what I came up with (sorry if it's a bit messy) 
re.compile("\[Customer03\](?:.|\s)*?Address:\s*(.+)\n") 
which works apart from when the the value is empty, such as Customer02 Telephone ... then it captures the next line.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem regular expressions are meant to solve. Your best bet is to parse out the data into structures first (possibly using regexs to aid in "chunking" the data).

Comment: it's your affirmation denying to regexes the ability to solve this problem that launched my desire to find a solution. Does this solution agree you ?

Comment: @eyquem: sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking there. I think I got a bit lost in the wording.

Comment: Certainly my wording, yes, as I am not a natural anglophone. I was trying to express that when I read your opinion that "This is not a problem regular expressions are meant to solve" , I understood that you think that solving the problem was exceeding their means. As I don't think so, it stimulated me to take up the challenge. And now, I would be interested by your view_point (as anyone else's one in fact) on my code.

Answer (score 1):

What format is the data in? Is it a string? If efficiency is not a major issue, the obvious thing would be to slice the string:

```
start = cdata.find("[Customer01]")
end = cdata.find("[Customer02]")
result = re.search('Name:\s*(.+)', cdata[start:end]).group(0)
```

or more tersely:

```
name = re.search('Name:\s*(.+)', cdata[cdata.find("[Customer01]"): cdata.find("[Customer02]")]).group(0)
```

EDIT: or with error checking:

```
start = cdata.find("[Customer01]")
end = cdata.find("[Customer02]")
result = re.search('Name:\s*(.+)', cdata[start:end])
if result: name = result.group(0)
```

Comment: This is quite nice, but needs multiple passes through the string of course. Also, what happens if there happens to be only one customer in the data at any time?

Comment: Well if `find` doesn't find anything, it just returns -1. So as long as the starting field is found, no problem. If neither is found, then the re returns None, so that should be checked. Regarding speed -- well it's not the most efficient thing but I assume the OP isn't doing this very often, or else he or she would just parse the whole thing into a useful data structure.

Comment: Regexes are actually a very efficient way to parse things once they are compiled into a state machine -- probably about as efficient as it gets. I even know of implementations which emit machine code just like a JIT compiler: one `goto` per symbol! And if the regex doesn't need backtracking (and the given one doesn't) I would certainly not think that you can save speed or memory with your own parser here. However, if multiple searches have to start at the beginning, you are absolutely right, of course

Comment: @Felix Dombek, indeed, regexes can be very efficient; we are certainly in agreement there. But speed is not always the most important concern -- if the data needs to be accessed frequently, a well-designed data structure may be far easier to read and maintain than a collection of regexes. (Though I suppose one could create a maintainable interface to a regex-based back end in such a case.)

Comment: That's true (reading and maintaining) but to get a regex readable one should do something along the lines of this anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180688/composed-regular-expressions-breaking-a-regex-down-into-a-readable-form which also results in quite maintainable code, I definitely recommend this as good practice ...

Answer (score 0):

The `re` module provides no way to limit the range of the match.  You can match against a substring if you already know the indexes you want to limit them to.

Comment: « The re module provides no way to limit the range of the match. » But Python does: -----------------------------------> convenient_results = [ match.groups() for i,match in enumerate(pattern.finditer(data)) if i in matches_to_select ]

Answer (score 0):

Does the following suit to you ?

```
ch = """
[Customer01]
Name: Mr Smith
Address: Somewhere 
Telephone: 01234567489

[Customer02] 
Name: Mr Jones 
Address: Laandon 
Telephone: 

[Customer03] 
Name: Mr Brown 
Address: Bibble 
Telephone: 077764312

[Customer04]
Name: Mr Acarid
Address: Carpet 
Telephone: 88864592

[Customer05] 
Name: Mr Johannes 
Address: Zuidersee 
Telephone: 

[Customer06] 
Name: Mr Bringt 
Address: Babylon 
Telephone: 077747812

[Customer07] 
Name: Ms Amanda 
Address: Madrid 
Telephone: 187354988

[Customer88] 
Name: Ms Heighty 
Address: Cairo 
Telephone: 11128

"""

import re

blah = '''Enter the characteristics you want the items to be selected upon :
- the Customer's numbers (separated by commas) : '''
must = {'Customer' : re.findall('0*(\d+)',raw_input(blah)) ,'Name':[],'Address':[],'Telephone':[] }

while True:
    y = raw_input('- strings desired in the Names (void to finish) : ')
    if y:  must['Name'].append(y)
    else:  break

while True:
    y = raw_input('- strings desired in the Addresses (void to finish) : ')
    if y:  must['Address'].append(y)
    else:  break

while True:
    y = raw_input('- strings desired in the Telephone numbers (void to finish) : ')
    if y:  must['Telephone'].append(y)
    else:  break

pat = re.compile('\[Customer0*(?P<Customer>\d+)].*\nName:(?P<Name>.*)\nAddress:(?P<Address>.*)\nTelephone:(?P<Telephone>.*)')

print ch,'\n\nmust==',must,'\n\n'

print '\n'.join( repr(match.groups()) for match in pat.finditer(ch)
                 if any((x==match.group(k) if k=='Customer' else x in match.group(k))
                        for k in must.iterkeys() for x in must[k]) )
```

For example entering data so as

```
must== {'Customer': ['003', '8', '6'], 'Telephone': ['645'], 'Name': [], 'Address': ['Laa']}
```

the result is

```
('2', ' Mr Jones ', ' Laandon ', ' ')
('3', ' Mr Brown ', ' Bibble ', ' 077764312')
('4', ' Mr Acarid', ' Carpet ', ' 88864592')
('6', ' Mr Bringt ', ' Babylon ', ' 077747812')
```

Notice that in this result, the portion corresponding to Customer88 isn't present, despite the fact that '8' has been put as a desired number. That is obtained by testing

```
x==match.group(k) if k=='Customer'
```

Otherwise the test is

```
x in match.group(k)
```

Hence the "A if condition_upon_k else B" expression