# Python readability regex

Tags: python, regex, readability

Python is about reading the code and understands what is happening. That is what I like about Python. Regex is in general hard to read. [codinghorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) explains this very well, and also made a suggestion to split up the regular expression in multiple line for readability.

## Code

F.e I have the working regex :

```
vms_list = re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', vms)
```

I would like to do something like :

```
vms_list = re.findall(r'
    "     # find token " 
    [^"]  # find any char which is no " token
    *     # repeat this until
    "     # token " is found again
    ', vms)
```

Solution  :

```
  vms_list = re.findall(r"""   # start
                        ["]     # find token double quote, surround with square brackets
                        [^"]    # find token which is not token double quote
                        *       # repeat this until
                        ["]     # # until token double quote is found again
                        """, vms, re.VERBOSE)  # close
```

## Research

I have searched for multiline regex, with many response, but not about the readability of regex.
[Composed Regular Expressions - breaking a regex down into a readable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180688/composed-regular-expressions-breaking-a-regex-down-into-a-readable-form) from 2009 came close but without a solution.

IgnorePatternWhitespace is advised to used like in codehorror blog. But I can not find it, or something similar, for Python.

## Readability

This would really improve the readability of my Python regex. 
Is something like this possible in Python?

Comment: Yes, use the [VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) flag.

Comment: @undefined-is-not-a-function Looks very attractive. I tried but it does not work for me. The token " makes this example complex. Could you give an example?

Comment: @Bernard use triple quotes to split for splitting a string to multiple lines. `re.findall(r"""Your mu"l"ti"line regex here""", re.VERBOSE)`

Comment: @msvalkon Thanks I tried but the output of the regex differ from original. What is my mistake?

Comment: I used square bracklets and now my regex returns the same result as the original. Thanks for your help "Undefined is not a function" and msvalkon